# Magento 2.1 override module-catalog-inventory/Block/Plugin/ProductView.php

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to override ProductView.php because minimum quantity is 1 in Magento, when ik change the following line to 0.5 the minimum is 0.5 (works when i change it in core).

```
$params['minAllowed']  = max((float)$stockItem->getQtyMinAllowed(), 0.5);
```

The code so far (that is not working):

DI.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\CatalogInventory\Block\Plugin\ProductView" type="Jilco\decimunit\Block\Plugin\ProductView" />
</config>
```

Registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Jilco_decimunit',
    __DIR__
);
```

Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <module setup_version="1.0.0" name="Jilco_decimunit"/>
</config>
```

productview.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Jilco\decimunit\Block\Plugin;

use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;

class ProductView
{
    /**
     * @var StockRegistryInterface
     */
    private $stockRegistry;

    /**
     * @param StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
     */
    public function __construct(
        StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
    ) {
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View $block
     * @param array $validators
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetQuantityValidators(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View $block,
        array $validators
    ) {
        $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem(
            $block->getProduct()->getId(),
            $block->getProduct()->getStore()->getWebsiteId()
        );

        $params = [];
        $params['minAllowed']  = max((float)$stockItem->getQtyMinAllowed(), 0.5);
        if ($stockItem->getQtyMaxAllowed()) {
            $params['maxAllowed'] = $stockItem->getQtyMaxAllowed();
        }
        if ($stockItem->getQtyIncrements() > 0) {
            $params['qtyIncrements'] = (float)$stockItem->getQtyIncrements();
        }
        $validators['validate-item-quantity'] = $params;

        return $validators;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have used module name `Jilco_decimunit` it should be `Jilco_Decimunit` also you have to capitalise the Module name in directory name as well as class name throughout the module

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not set preference for a plugin. Event thought it is possible it violate the essence of plugins. Instead you should create your own plugin which will be executed after the core plugin in which you will handle your custom logic to produce required output. To achieve this:

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View">
    <plugin name="YOUR_PLUGIN_NAME" type="Jilco\Decimunit\Plugin\Block\ProductViewPlugin" />
  </type>
</config>
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <module setup_version="1.0.0" name="Jilco_Decimunit">
       <sequence>
         <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
       </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Plugin\Block\ProductViewPlugin.php

```
    <?php
namespace Jilco\Decimunit\Plugin\Block;

class ProductViewPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View $block
     * @param array $validators
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetQuantityValidators(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View $block,
        array $validators
    ) {
        //execute your logic here
    }
}
```

And pay attention to your capital letters in namespaces, module names and xml paths. I found that you made some mistakes there.

Comment: Do i need to use Catalog in DI.xml or CatalogInventory?

Comment: Magento\Catalog, we are not writing plugin for a plugin which is in catalogInventory but for a class' public method getQuantityValidators in Catalog module. I strongly recommend to read documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: Bartosz, i think im on the good way. Thanks for that! Only when i use the ProductViewPlugin.php as you described above the whole quantity field is gone.... When is put the normal code from productview inside (with getQtyMinAllowed(), 0.5) the quantity shows up again but 0.5 is not possible...